# CUDA- using thread's index to access array elements more than one time

Tags: arrays, cuda

I wanted to use thread id to access an array which is defined as a global variable.
But I face the problem in summing by one. Take a look below:

```
// initial array myU[0..3]={0,0,0,0}, myindex[0..3]={0,1,1,3}
1- tid=0,1,2,3 //tid is threads index
2- id=myindex[tid]; //id=0,1,1,3
3- myU[id]=myU[id]+1; 
4- if (myU[id]>1)
     //print("id"); // it should print '1'
```

I supposed after running line 3 I have myU[0]=1,**myU[1]=2**,myU[3]=1. But `myU` array has some strange value, like as: myU[0]=0, myU[1]=1, myU[3]=3. I don't know why.

My final goal is to have the id(in line 4), which they summed by one, more than one time).

Answer (score 4):

If `myU[1]` is written by 2 different threads then the result is undefined and you need to use `atomicAdd` to obtain `myU[1]==2`

CUDA programming guide states:

> If a non-atomic instruction executed by a warp writes to the same
>   location in global or shared memory for more than one of the threads
>   of the warp, the number of serialized writes that occur to that
>   location varies depending on the compute capability of the device and
>   which thread performs the final write is undefined.

Comment: I used atomicAdd(&myU[id],1), but I still get the same wrong rsualt!!

Comment: Then you should probably provide a complete, compilable code that demonstrates the problem.  In fact, SO expects: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance. "